# ruby timeout not working with external url

Tags: ruby

The code below should raise Timeout::Error after 1 second. It does NOT raise after 1 second though. It raises after the url actually times out. I'm trying to figure out why.

```
Timeout::timeout(1) { Net::HTTP.get('bogusurlaaaaa.com','index.html') }
```

$ ruby -v

```
ruby 1.9.2p320
```

I'm not using 1.8.7 which has the "green threads" problem. So I shouldn't need SystemTimer gem

This works:

```
Timeout::timeout(1) { sleep(20) }
```

My assumption is that net/http uses some system libraries and the ruby timeout thread isn't able to kill this after 1 second? Just a guess.

Any help is appreciated! I also used Mechanize to do the get, but this uses net/http I believe and had the same issue.

Note: I'm executing this via irb on both a mac (10.8.2) and ubuntu (12.04)

Note: If you're testing this multiple times you'll need to change the bogusurl to something else with each test, otherwise the bogus one will get cached and you'll get a quick response.

Comment: Did you tried to run on ruby 2.0.0?

Comment: yes, my ubuntu instance use ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: try "www.youtube.com".I thought it was because the bad url

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code,it works for me. and my ruby is 1.9.3-p327,you can update your ruby version and try it again.

or you can try this below:

```
  Net::HTTP.start('bogusurlaaaaa.com', open_timeout: 1, read_timeout: 1){|h| h.get '/'}
```

Comment: did you try changing the bogusurl with each test? i'm installing 1.9.3-p327 to test. see note above about the url caching

Comment: Works for me with ruby 1.9.3p392 on OSX

Comment: yeah , this url is not known.

Comment: can you guys try this one: Timeout::timeout(1) { Net::HTTP.get('india-tours.org','index.html') }

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0] didn't work either

Comment: I tried,it works.but then it turns to name or service not known

Comment: thanks! very strange. i'm using 1.9.3p327 now and still not working. my friend is doing it on his machine too

Comment: you should try youtube.com first.if it works, then it is problem with the url

Comment: youtube.com return the html so no exception is thrown

Comment: are you testing in console? or in your controller?

Comment: you can try youtube with setting timeout=0.01. anyway,your code is no problem. it works well. but the url may causes problem

Comment: youtube won't work as a test case. i need this to work with sites that DO NOT load. it needs to throw this exception: Timeout::Error after 1 second for a site that doesn't load. thanks for checking! i'm looking into how this works under the hood.